# Different behavior in interpolating docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, interpolation, docker-swarm

Different behavior in interpolating .env files when run docker compose up and docker stack deploy

I have one .env file with content

`VAR_NAME=test$TEST`

and when I run docker compose up and execute echo on this variable in container

`echo $VAR_NAME`

I got output: `test`

But, if I run docker stack deploy with same .env file

I got correct output: `test$TEST`

I know I can use escaping and quotes, but that will fail docker stack deploy, because docker stack deploy interpolates by default.

Is it possible to somehow do the same for docker compose up like docker stack deploy without changing the variable itself?

Comment: What doy ou mean by "interpolation"? Can you share more details abou how you start the containers?

Comment: how about setting `VAR_NAME` from inside your docker-compose.yml using the `.environment` property with the escaping? You can leave your .env unchanged for docker stack, and rely on the overridden value when running `docker compose up`

Comment: I did a little bit of research around [this question](/q/77797951) yesterday and discovered that, while Compose `env_file:` does variable interpolation, `docker run --env-file` does not.  There's not an option to change how either tool behaves.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes. Got undefined behavior, I [found --skip-interpolation flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_config/), maybe this will help for swarm, I'll try later.